# Openxlsx2 Pivot Table Layout Options

Tags: r, openxlsx2

I am wondering if there is (or will be) a way to change the layout of a pivot table. For example, I would like my pivot table to print without Subtotals and in Tabular form like in the picture:

[Excel screenshot of pivot table layout options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gZXx.png)

```r
library(openxlsx2)

wb <- wb_workbook() %>% 
      wb_add_worksheet() %>%
      wb_add_data(x = mtcars, inline_strings = F)

wb$add_numfmt(dims = wb_dims(x = mtcars, cols = "disp"), numfmt = "$ #,###")

df <- wb_data(wb)

# basic pivot table with filter, rows, cols and data
wb$add_pivot_table(
  df,
  rows = "cyl", cols = "gear",
  data = c("disp", "hp"),
  fun = c("sum", "count"),
  params = list(
    numfmt = c(formatCode = "$ ###", formatCode = "#")
  ))

wb$open()
```

This code is from the [openxlsx2 documentation on pivot tables](https://janmarvin.github.io/ox2-book/chapters/openxlsx2_pivot_tables.html)

I would like for the table to *automatically* print with the layout being in tabular form and without subtotals

[openxlsx2]

Comment: This is [not yet possible, it's the second part of this pull request](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/pull/833), but Stack Overflow is not really the place to post feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

With release 1.2 this is now possible:

(The `wb_add_pivot_table()` function and especially the `param` argument could use some documentation, but ... yeah ...)

```r
library(openxlsx2)
packageVersion("openxlsx2")
#> [1] '1.2'

wb <- wb_workbook() %>%
  wb_add_worksheet("table") %>%
  wb_add_worksheet("data") %>%
  wb_add_data(x = datasets::esoph)

df <- wb_data(wb)

wb <- wb %>%
  wb_add_pivot_table(
    df, dims = "A3", sheet = "table",
    rows = "agegp", cols = "tobgp", data = "ncases",
    param = list(
      compact = FALSE, outline = FALSE, compact_data = FALSE,
      row_grand_totals = FALSE, col_grand_totals = FALSE
    )
  ) %>% 
  wb_open()
#> Warning: will not open file when not interactive
```

[image: table screenshot from excel]